# "Error occurred during initialization of VM" in linux

Tags: java, linux, heap-memory

I am trying to run java command in linux server it was running well but today when I tried to run java I got some error-

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

my memory space is -

```
root@vps [~]# free -m
         total       used       free   
Mem:     8192        226        7965    
-/+ buf: 226         7965
Swap:    0           0          0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you are using 8 gb ram at that time. look at used column of `-/+` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine did not have enough memory at that time to service the JVM's request for memory to start the program.   I expect that you have 8 Gb of memory in the machine and that you use a 64-bit JVM.

I would suggest you add some swap space to the system to let it handle spikes in memory usage, and then figure out where the spike came from.

Comment: +1 Adding some swap space is a good idea even if it doesn't help here. I would add 2-16 GB of swap.

Answer (score 0):

Which VM are you using? What is the maximum memory size you are trying to use?

If you are using 32-bit JVM on Windows and you are using close to the maximum it can access on your system, it can be impacted by memory fragmentation. You may have a similar problem.